# Magento: Redirect to a specific category after adding a product to cart

Tags: magento

how can I redirect the user to a specific category after adding a product to cart ?

I use Magento 1.4.1.1

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no way to do this with out small programming effort. The simplest way i can think of is to use return_url parameter for "add to cart" form. Edit catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml template by adding there hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://google.com" />
```

after button tag. In result after adding product to cart you will be redirected to pointed site.

Hope this will help you.